# PHP simplexml count string

Tags: php

I am working on a XML and I used simplexml.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(a xml file); //this website is just chosen randomly 


    if(!in_array($iindex,$category_type)){
        $category_type[] = $iindex;
        $category_type[$iindex] = 1;
    } else {
        $category_type[$iindex] = $category_type[$iindex] + 1;
    }
}

foreach($category_type as $key=> $value){
    echo " number of $key is ". $value;
}
```

the result I got currently is

```
number of 0 is Really Funny Jokes
number of Really Funny Jokes is 13
number of 1 is Clean jokes
```

The result I am expecting is

```
    number of Really Funny Jokes is 13
    number of Clean jokes is 6
    number of Good jokes is 2
```

Could someone help with my code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!array_key_exists($iindex, $category_type)){
//$category_type[] = $iindex; //**remove this line**
$category_type[$iindex] = 1;
} else {
```

what that line is doing is it's inserting an entry in array with index 0,1,2.. and value as your key..

And use array_key_exists..

Comment: no, if I remove that line, the result become `number of Really Funny Jokes is 1
number of Clean jokes is 1
number of Good jokes is 1
number of Kids Jokes is 1
number of animal jokes is 1
number of short humor jokes is 1`

Comment: thats because u r using in_array, while u should use array_key_exists

Comment: You Rock!Rajat! been looking for an solution quite long time